# opencv open image without jerking

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am using opencv2 to open a series of images (On raspberry pi) I find the transition is very jerky (ie opening the image) is there any way to smooth this?
The code snippet below is what I am using atm (I guess I should use mat:)

```
 void loadImage()
{
int nImages = 6;
for (int i = 0; i < nImages; ++i)
 {
IplImage *image;
char filename[100];
strcpy(filename, "images/");

char frameNo[10];
sprintf(frameNo, "%03i", i);

strcat(filename, frameNo);
strcat(filename, ".jpg");

image = cvLoadImage(filename);
cvNamedWindow("pic");
cvShowImage("pic",image);
cvMoveWindow("pic", 0, 0);
cvWaitKey(1000);
 }
}
```

Comment: The magic phrase you're probably looking for is "double buffering". That, and not doing IO in your UI thread. Load the images in advance in their own thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load your images either in other thread, or before the loop if you're lazy. It should be something like this:

```
void loadImages() {
IplImage *images[NUM_IMAGES];

 images[0] = cvLoadImage("filename1.jpg");
 images[1] = cvLoadImage("filename1.jpg");
 images[2] = cvLoadImage("filename1.jpg");
 .
 .
 . (etc)
}

void showImages(){
    loadImages();
    for (int i = 0; i < nImages; ++i){

        cvNamedWindow("pic");
        cvShowImage("pic",images[i]);
        cvMoveWindow("pic", 0, 0);
        cvWaitKey(1000);
    }
}
```

Of course, array of pinters to images `*images[]` should be declared as global, or you should pass it from `loadimages()` function to `showImages()` (Better solution).

Comment: The answers are helpful and the images are loading much smoother but still a bit ragged, so I will look at using threads as the next step